# Jquery not working properly in safari and IE11 but works fine in Firefox and with some fix to make it work in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made and album, with popup modal effect. it works fine in Firefox. at first it didnt worked in others. after some fix it worked in chrome but with some animation missing(width). when i click a image is should popup(animating width and height). in chrome,Safari and IE it popup fine, but image is out-width the '#popup' box, and only height is animating. whats the fix.?

HTML

```
<div id="popup"></div>
<div class="imageContainer">
  <ul id="list">

    <li><img src="img/thumpnails/IMG_3560.jpg" name="img/IMG_3560.jpg" class="imageGallery"

        alt="3560"></li>
    <li><img src="img/thumpnails/IMG_3562.jpg" name="img/IMG_3562.jpg" class="imageGallery"

        alt="3562"></li>
    <li><img src="img/thumpnails/IMG_3564.jpg" name="img/IMG_3564.jpg" class="imageGallery"

        alt="3564"></li>
    <li><img src="img/thumpnails/IMG_3565.jpg" name="img/IMG_3565.jpg" class="imageGallery"

        alt="3565"></li>
    <li><img src="img/thumpnails/IMG_3566.jpg" name="img/IMG_3566.jpg" class="imageGallery"

        alt="3566"></li>
    <li><img src="img/thumpnails/IMG_3567.jpg" name="img/IMG_3567.jpg" class="imageGallery"

        alt="3567"></li>
    <li><img src="img/thumpnails/IMG_3569.jpg" name="img/IMG_3569.jpg" class="imageGallery"

        alt="3569"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#popup{
    position: fixed;
    height: 90%;    
    background-color: rgba(80,80,80,0.99);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%); /* another way of making negative margin, for fixed elements*/
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    display: none;  
    border-radius: 3px; 
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;   
    padding:5px;
    z-index: 2000;
}

#popup img{
    height:90%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /*position: relative;*/
    /*border was deleted because it makes #popup to a constant width of around 4px, need to check border-box property */
}
#popup p{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #ffd98e;
    margin:0px;
    /*margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;*/
    /*text-align: center;   */
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;

}
#popup div{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    /*background-color: #f5f5f5;*/
    /*border-radius: 1px;*/
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 2002;
}
```

JS

```
    $(document).on("click",".imageGallery",function(){
        img = $(this).attr("name"); //image source      
        num = $(this).attr("alt"); //image name

        // $("#popup p").addClass("popupName");         
        // $("#popup img").addClass("popupImg");
        // $("#popup div").addClass("popupNameBg");
        $('#popup').html("<div> <p>Photo No: "+num+"</p> </div> <img src="+img+"></img>");      
        $('#popup').slideDown("300",function(){
            // $('#popup').html("<div> <p>"+num+"</p> </div> <img src="+img+"></img>");
            // $("#popup p").addClass("popupName");         
            // $("#popup img").addClass("popupImg");
            // $("#popup div").addClass("popupNameBg");
        })              
    })

    $('#popup').click(function(){           
            $('#popup').slideUp("300");
            // img = 0;
            // $('#popup img').remove();
            console.log(img+"third");
            // return false;
    })
```

Comment: in IE and safari, when i click a image for first time, the 'popup' box's width will be either .64px or 1.64px or close. and when i click it again, it gets okay, filling the entire width of image it contains.

Comment: pls reduce your code to the relevant parts and provide an minimal working example .... pls see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you've said it works in firefox, then said "chrome,Safari and IE it popup fine" so what browser has an issue or is it all browser?

Comment: the popup is coming, but some issue with width property, in first click the width of image container(here #popup) is like around 2px, and in second click it gets to normal.